# Configuring Riak - Can't find a file like /etc/riak/app.config

Tags: riak

I have installed Riak on a Debian system from the package riak_2.0.1-1_amd64.deb, and I'm trying to change the configuration so I use the LevelDB Backend for 2i (so I can use secondary indexes).

http://docs.basho.com/riak/latest/dev/taste-of-riak/querying/ says to edit (usually) /etc/riak/app.config, but there is no such file. I can find /etc/riak/riak.conf but that has settings like

```
something.else.value = 12345
```

and nothing like

```
{storage_backend, riak_kv_bitcask_backend}
```

described on the docs page.

I'm sure its trivial, but trivially what! Help!!!

Answer (score 3):

Configuration in Riak 2.0+ is handled by a `riak.conf` file that is located in each node's `/etc` directory. More information can be found in [this document](http://docs.basho.com/riak/latest/ops/advanced/configs/configuration-files/).

Comment: link is unfortunately dead

Answer (score 1):

I think in the newer versions riak.conf is located at: etc/riak/riak.conf

Answer (score 0):

Looks like /etc/riak/riak.conf is the one to use. I set

```
storage_backend = leveldb
```

and secondary indexes work now.

Thanks